# Instantiate component from a directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I need to implement custom date picker.
For this I have date-picker.directive and select-date.component (dialog window).

I attach directive through attribute in html and can process events. By click event directive should call dialog window (it's our component).

```
<button class="btn" type="button" date-picker>
```

But how can I instantiate select-date.component from a directive?
How to add a new component into DOM?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type of the component you can just inject it into the directive

```
export class DatePickerDirective {
  constructor(private selectDateComponent:SelectDateComponent) {}
}
```

If the directive should be able to access any type of component where it is applied then you can use the method explained in [How to access the Component on a Angular2 Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748575/how-to-access-the-component-on-a-angular2-directive/) (see also this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277)

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, your solution helps to get access for existed component. Is it possible to create a new instance of component and add it to DOM?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 for an example

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, thanks for your help, but your example shows how to create _component from component_. When I would like to find solution for _component from directive_.